# Bootstrap Controller not working in

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap controls are not working after hosting website in IIS. Is there any solution for solving this problem. This project is completely done.

Comment: IIS has nothing to do with bootstrap or any other javascript library. Where do you download bootstrap from? Do you use a local copy? Is so, did you copy it to the production site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check iis have permission to access folder contains bootstrap. You can do this by
 Open your site in Chrome

**Setting-> More options -> View source**

Click on "Bootstrap" link.

This problem may cause on some hosts if folder name contains .(dot), like **bootstrap-3.1.1**